# Sending Email through Guest user In salesforce Community is Not working As it is working with system admin?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am attempting to send an email through an Apex method called from an LWC in Salesforce Community(sending email to the address mentioned in input field I have given in my LWC). However, it is not working for guest users(Guest user profile have access to apex class), although it functions perfectly for internal users.

I have also experimented with sending emails from a Lightning Flow, as I came across this as a potential workaround in one of the articles, but unfortunately, it didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Email sending is not working for guest users. I have also checked the debug logs in that I can see Email queued But Not receiving at mailbox but checked with internal users for same mail address it worked perfectly fine.